# Force Auto Open Dialog in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, httpresponse, onedrive

FileRun has a beautiful File-Explorer Google-Drive styled. You can testdrive it here [FileRunDemoSite](https://demo.filerun.co/?username=admin&password=admin#/HOME/Office)

When I download a File I get to choose if I want to open the file directly in a Office Application.

[image: Open Dialog]

When I click on Office, google prompts me with a Chrome Open File Dialog. The File opens directly from the location instead of being savend in /downloads/ folder.

[image]

How can I achieve this behavior? All existing answers on SA state that this is not possible, so this might be interesting to others as well. Not even google has implemented this. Is there a cross-browser solution?

Onedrive does it as well:

[image]

Comment: This is a very attractive feature. However, when I click "Office" in the "Open with..." menu, nothing happens. I'm using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: I am on Chrome and Windows - it works great. I suspect this could be tuned because office is no official format.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to Thomas2D to get me on the right track. How it basically works is:

If you develop an application you can register a new protocol with the operation-system. `http://` will be handled by your default browser. `applicationX://` will be handled by applicationX, `ms-word://` will be handled by word. If you click on a link the browser/operating-system looks up which application should handle the protocol an pass the request on to this application.

For Office documents the URI is a bit more complex ms-`excel:ofv|u|http://contoso/Q4/budget.xls`. You can open it readonly/ for edit / as a template. Check out this document for a detailed description of all the options: [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx)

For other applications check the URI Schemes with that application.

**How to use it on a website:**

It is not advisable to set a link to an application in a Dom element href attribute. You have no way of checking if the application is installed or not.

If you use Javascript you can check if the request times out / fails and use `http://` instead.

. Set the protocol in a `href: window.location.href = encodeURI('ms-excel:ofe|u|http://example.com/excel.xlsx')` or by setting the the `location.protocol`, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_protocol.asp

There is a jQuery Plugin to do that :[jquery.applink.js](https://github.com/eusonlito/jquery.applink/blob/master/jquery.applink.js)

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that this is accomplished by starting application via specific url.

I know that this works on iOS for launching application. In iOS it was done by something (simillar to `mailto:example@example.com`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
window.location = "myapplication://myparams";
</script>
```

EDIT: I finally get it, you have to use application url scheme. For example, if you want to open your Excel file via browser, you have to use this JS code.

```
window.location.href = encodeURI('ms-excel:ofe|u|http://example.com/excel.xlsx');
```

Comment: the linked source talks about editing the registry. The javascript looks promising. Can you give me a working example?

Comment: Yes, it talks. But look at a beginning of the article. They are talking abourt Content-Type, which maybe important to do it..

Comment: If you have iPhone for example, open Safari and type fb:// dialog will pop up and Facebook aplication will be opened. :)

Comment: @Thomas2D you got me on the right path. Content-Type does not trigger open with an app. I want this answer to be a bit more complete, I am going to write an answer with some more information in it.